# Wordpress Plugin without any Host

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a blog hosted in wordpress. I bought a domain from GoDaddy and forwared it to my wordpress blog. Now, if I want to install any plugin to my site, I always get instructions like - download this and place it to that directory. How do I find that directory when I am using Wordpress's free bloggin service.

Comment: Try asking this question on superuser.com instead - you might find a better target audience.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you cannot upload plugins/themes to WordPress.com, even if you have a mapped domain.
http://support.wordpress.com/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

Host wordpress at GoDaddy - you already use them for domain registration - and then you can use plugins, as well as do much more, as wordpress.com is limited in many respects. Export your existing content from .com to your own wordpress install, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on wordpress.com, you can't use the plugins unfortunately. If you're on wordpress self-hosted, upload them by going to Plugins > Add New in the sidebar of the back-end of your site.